# PHPMailler sent email success but Reciever didn't receive email

Tags: phpmailer

I bought domain, host and email from Godaddy.
I am using phpMailer for my website's email function.
PhpMailer is showing email sent successfully but receiver didn't receive email.
I have put my php code and phpMailler debug log below.
Many thanks for your any suggestion..

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '/home/vv0srjz4gnsz/public_html/system/library/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require '/home/vv0srjz4gnsz/public_html/system/library/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '/home/vv0srjz4gnsz/public_html/system/library/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);  
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; 
$mail->Port = 25; 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
    
$mail->AddAddress('receiver@email.com', 'Receiver');
$mail->SetFrom('sender@email.com', 'Sender');
$mail->Subject = 'My Subject';
$mail->Body = 'Mail contents';
$mail->Username = 'auth@godaddyemaildomain.com'; 
$mail->Password = '!mypassword';

try{
    if ($mail->send()) {
      echo 'email sent success';
    } else {
      echo 'failed to send';
      echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
} catch(Exception $e){
    //Something went bad
    echo "Fail - " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

Result:

```
2023-02-17 09:53:11 Connection: opening to localhost:25, timeout=300, options=array()
2023-02-17 09:53:11 Connection: opened
2023-02-17 09:53:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-sg2plzcpnl453267.prod.sin2.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.95 #2 Fri, 17 Feb 2023 02:53:11 -0700 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.godaddyDomain.com
2023-02-17 09:53:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-sg2plzcpnl453267.prod.sin2.secureserver.net Hello www.godaddyDomain.com [127.0.0.1]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-PIPE_CONNECT250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<sender@godaddyDomain.com>
2023-02-17 09:53:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<receiver@godaddyDomain.com>
2023-02-17 09:53:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2023-02-17 09:53:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Fri, 17 Feb 2023 09:53:11 +0000
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Mr Receiver <receiver@godaddyDomain.com>
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Mr Sender <sender@godaddyDomain.com>
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: My Subject
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <muLYFVVw4LfUEMaV9Ot6WWxwnYHXYNs9UB1Mf0atZLU@www.godaddyDomain.com>
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.1.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: Mail contents
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2023-02-17 09:53:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1pSxQV-00HNWK-K8
2023-02-17 09:53:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2023-02-17 09:53:12 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 sg2plzcpnl453267.prod.sin2.secureserver.net closing connection
2023-02-17 09:53:12 Connection: closed
email sent success
```

Any suggestion is appreciated..

Thanksss.

Comment: You're doing everything right here, nothing wrong with your code. Check your spam folder, and if it's not in there, talk to GoDaddy support.

Answer (score 0):

There are a myriad of reasons why your post was possibly not been received.
SPF, DMARC, DKIM, Blacklists...

It would help to start with your main.cf file parameters.
Have you inspected your mail logs?
Use the "tail" command and post any relevant errors.